# krusader - calculate size on spacebar press

Tags: 14.04, 18.04, krusader

In ubuntu 18.04 in krusader (v 2.6.0) when i press spacebar the directory size is not calculated. in ubuntu 14.04 it was the case. how can i configure the space calculation as it was previously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need version 2.7.0.

That option got [deleted](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=379170) [intentionally](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=379170#c3) as it was ugly code but it got [added back](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=379170#c19) into Krusader with version 2.7.0.

Comment 3 in the bug report:

> **Alex Bikadorov 2017-04-26 19:20:59 UTC**
>
> Well, removing the "space key" feature was intended. My assumption was that it is not really needed: Instead of pressing space a lot of times you select all dirs at once and press the shortcut one time.
>   I thought its a better solution - no waiting anymore for each dir - but I guess I was wrong.

Comment 21:

> **szecsodimlaszlo 2018-05-30 16:28:43 UTC**
>
> I can confirm that this issue is fixed in the version 2.7.0.
>
> Thank you, @Alex Bikadorov. I do appreciate your work.